# How to format Boxerrorbars in gnuplot

Tags: colors, format, gnuplot, box

I am trying to create in `gnuplot` a graph that is using `Boxerrorbars` but I am only getting lines instead of boxes. How can I format it properly in order to get solid color boxes (with the errorlines)?
My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

reset session
set colorsequence classic

$Data <<EOD
#srvr   pad type    o/s h/s m/s ltnc    kb/s
0   0   Sets    9460.76 --- --- 0.10300 955.14  
1   0   Sets    6372.56 --- --- 0.14800 643.36  
2   0   Sets    6803.38 --- --- 0.13800 686.85  
0   0   Sets    8232.04 --- --- 0.11600 2382.64 
1   0   Sets    6239.53 --- --- 0.14700 1805.93 
2   0   Sets    6607.20 --- --- 0.14300 1912.35 
0   0   Sets    8620.21 --- --- 0.11000 4650.04 
1   0   Sets    6273.20 --- --- 0.14900 3383.98 
2   0   Sets    6338.06 --- --- 0.14900 3418.97 
0   0   Sets    8563.95 --- --- 0.10800 8910.03 
1   0   Sets    6018.97 --- --- 0.15900 6262.21 
2   0   Sets    6660.93 --- --- 0.13900 6930.11 
0   0   Sets    8420.58 --- --- 0.11200 850.12  
1   0   Sets    6277.14 --- --- 0.14900 633.73  
2   0   Sets    7256.48 --- --- 0.13100 732.60  
0   0   Sets    8144.12 --- --- 0.11600 2357.19 
1   0   Sets    6146.69 --- --- 0.15300 1779.06 
2   0   Sets    6689.36 --- --- 0.14100 1936.13 
0   0   Sets    8326.71 --- --- 0.11600 4491.72 
1   0   Sets    6129.93 --- --- 0.15400 3306.69 
2   0   Sets    6617.88 --- --- 0.14200 3569.91 
0   0   Sets    8018.55 --- --- 0.12200 8342.59 
1   0   Sets    6340.77 --- --- 0.14800 6597.01 
2   0   Sets    5800.46 --- --- 0.16600 6034.86 
0   0   Sets    9517.29 --- --- 0.09900 960.85  
1   0   Sets    6418.94 --- --- 0.14500 648.04  
2   0   Sets    6264.59 --- --- 0.14900 632.46  
0   0   Sets    8658.58 --- --- 0.10900 2506.09 
1   0   Sets    6103.07 --- --- 0.15700 1766.44 
2   0   Sets    7106.86 --- --- 0.13100 2056.97 
0   0   Sets    8818.82 --- --- 0.10900 4757.17 
1   0   Sets    6125.73 --- --- 0.15400 3304.43 
2   0   Sets    6915.42 --- --- 0.13600 3730.42 
0   0   Sets    9063.55 --- --- 0.10500 9429.82 
1   0   Sets    6089.46 --- --- 0.15600 6335.54 
2   0   Sets    6701.47 --- --- 0.13800 6972.29 
EOD

ColG = 1
ColF = 2
ColS = 4

set table $Group 
    plot $Data u (column(ColG)) smooth freq
unset table
print $Group

set table $Filter
    plot $Data u (column(ColF)) smooth freq
unset table
print $Filter

set table $Dummy
    array Group[|$Group|-6]         # gnuplot creates 6 extra lines
    array Filter[|$Filter|-6]
    plot $Group u (Group[$0+1]=$1) w table
    plot $Filter u (Filter[$0+1]=$1) w table
unset table

print Group
print Filter

Check(i,j) = Group[i]==column(ColG) && Filter[j]==column(ColF) ? column(ColS) : NaN
set print $Data3
    do for [i=1:|Group|] {
        do for [j=1:|Filter|] {
            undef var STATS*
            stats $Data u (Check(i,j)) nooutput
            if (exists('STATS_mean') && exists('STATS_stddev')) {
                print Group[i], Filter[j], STATS_mean, STATS_stddev
            }
        }
        print ""; print ""
    }  
set print
print $Data3

set output 'server_set_throughput.png'
set terminal png size 1000,800
set xtics ("Server 1" 1, "Server 2" 2, "Server 3" 3)
set xrange[0:4]
set yrange[0:10000]
set ylabel "Average Throughput for SET (Operations/Second)" font ",12"
set title "Server's SET Throughput" font "Helvetica,16"
set tics nomirror
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
unset key

plot for [i=0:|Group|-1] $Data3 u ($1+1):3:4 index i w boxerrorbars
```

and the output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1) The width of the boxes is controlled by "set boxwidth", unless you give a 4th column of data that contains the width.  I don't see any such command in your script, but from the output it looks like the width has somehow become set to 0 or near-zero. Add an explicit command `set boxwidth 0.5`

2) The fill style defaults to `empty`.  If you want solid boxes, use

```
  set style fill solid border
```

Giving the "border" keyword with no following set of line properties will use the same color and line type for the error bars as for the boxes themselves.  If you want to highlight the error bars, use something like

```
set style fill solid border linecolor "black"
```